# Php mysql prevent dropdown duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, dropdown

I would like to prevent drop-down option duplicate in my edit page..

This is my query:

```
$res= mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM Acc_skills
INNER JOIN Accounts ON 
Accounts.Role_ID = Acc_skills.FK_Role_ID 
INNER JOIN Skills ON 
Skills.Skills_id = Acc_skills.FK_Skills_ID
WHERE Acc_skills.Acc_skills_id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
echo '<option value= '.$row[3].' selected="selected">'.$row[3].' </option>';
echo '<option id="Low" value="Low">Low</option>
      <option id="Average" value="Average">Average</option>
      <option value="High">High</option>
</select>';
?>
```

I have managed to pull out the skill level data from my database (Eg, High), however, it shows duplicate drop down option now (Eg, there are 2 "High" options now). 
As the skill level option is manually typed in, how do i prevent having duplicate drop down options?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: then exclude the "High" level skill in your query

Comment: what is the value of $row[3]?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT...`?

Comment: The value of $row[3] is the skill level of the current record selected from the database, it can be high, average or low depending on the database record

Comment: and than u want to use selected="" according the database value right?

Comment: yes, it should reflect according to the database value

Comment: alright, answer provided... chk it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, you need to use `selected=""` option as per database value. you can use like that:

```
<select>
<option <?=($row[3] == 'Low' ? 'selected=""' : '')?> id="Low" value="Low">Low</option>
<option <?=($row[3] == 'Average' ? 'selected=""' : '')?> id="Average" value="Average">Average</option>
<option <?=($row[3] == 'High' ? 'selected=""' : '')?> value="High">High</option>
</select>
```

**Explanation:**

If `$row[3]` is equal to "Average" or "High" or "Low" than select related option menu and add selected="" attribute in `<option>` tag.

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions becuase `mysql_*` extension is deprecated and not available in `PHP 7`.

Comment: Thank you! i got it now! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

first of all:

1- Please travel from mysql into mysqli or PDO , i suggest PDO.

2- if duplicated data in your database use `"SELECT DISTINCT"` for fetching result.

3-if you have static option try like this:

```
<?php 
echo "<select>";
echo '<option value= '.$row[3].' selected="selected">'.$row[3].' </option>';
echo '<option id="Low" value="Low">Low</option>
      <option id="Average" value="Average">Average</option>
      <option value="High">High</option>
</select>';
?>
```

or if you have fetching all rows act like this:

```
 echo "<select>";
    echo "<option id=Low value=Low >Low</option>
          <option id=Average value=Average>Average</option>
          <option value=High>High</option>";
        foreach($result as $index){    
         echo " < optionvalue =$index[3] selected = 'selected' > $index[3]</option > ";   
       }
     echo "</select>";
```